# File upload doesn't terminate (freezes near the end) in Safari

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, file-upload, safari

I'm running a test server under the latest Django 2 release (Python3.6) on Mac OS X. My applications seem to work well across both Safari 11.0.2 and Chrome (build 63) except for one anoying detail. I've got this file upload form:

```
class BulkForm(AssemblyForm):  # AssemblyForm itself defines a Char field.
    file = forms.FileField(required=True, label='Input file')
```

That is handled by the following view (I've reduced it to the bare minimum for this example):

```
def formtest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BulkForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            upload = request.FILES['file']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('submissions'))
    bulk = BulkForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'bulk_form': bulk})
```

And the template:

```
...
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bulk">
                    <div class="container my-4">
                        <form role="form" method="post"
                              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ bulk_form.as_p }}
                            <button type="submit" name="bulk-form"
                                    class="btn btn-primary bg-dark">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
...
```

In Safari the upload sometimes freezes even when I try the same file: sometimes it uploads successfully, sometimes it freezes. There is a correlation between file size and its chances of getting stuck. To investigate this issue, I've implemented my own upload handler:

```
class SizeLimitedUploadedFile(uploadedfile.UploadedFile):
    def __init__(self, name, content_type, size, charset, content_type_extra=None):
        file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
            buffering=settings.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE, delete=False,
            suffix=f'.upload.{name.split(".", 1)[1]}',
            dir=settings.FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR
        )
        super().__init__(file, file.name, content_type, 0, charset, content_type_extra)
        self.error = None

    def write(self, chunk: bytes) -> int:
        """
        :param chunk: bytes to write
        :return: the number of bytes written
        :raises FileSizeLimitReached: if file size reached
        """
        newsize = self.size + len(chunk)
        if newsize <= settings.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE:
            self.file.write(chunk)
            self.size = newsize
            return len(chunk)
        self.error = FileSizeLimitReached
        raise FileSizeLimitReached

    def writelines(self, chunks: Iterable[bytes]):
        """
        :param chunks: bytes to write
        :raises FileSizeLimitReached: if file size reached
        """
        for chunk in chunks:
            self.write(chunk)


class TestFileUploadHandler(uploadhandler.FileUploadHandler):
    """
    File upload handler to stream uploads into memory (used for small files).
    """

    def new_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create the file object to append to as data are coming in.
        """
        print('creating new')
        super().new_file(*args, **kwargs)
        self.file = SizeLimitedUploadedFile(
            self.file_name, self.content_type, 0,
            self.charset, self.content_type_extra
        )
        self.counter = 0

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        self.counter += 1
        print(f'receiving batch {self.counter}')
        if self.file.error is None:
            with suppress(FileSizeLimitReached):
                self.file.write(raw_data)

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        print('complete')
        self.file.seek(0)
        return self.file
```

I then replaced default upload handlers in `settings.py` and tried to upload the same file several times. When the upload terminates as expected, I always see 1250 calls to `TestFileUploadHandler.receive_data_chunk`. When it freezes, the counter stays around 1239-1245 calls. I've only seen this behaviour in Safari. Chrome has been working well with built-in handlers as well as with my custom handler – it never freezes. I've tried searching the web for this and so far the closest hit is a [thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/file-upload-script-hangs-on-safari.672301/) from 2009 about an old WebKit bug. I've followed the thread to no avail. How can I fix this?

**Update**

I've run tests on the latest versions of Firefox and Opera. Both work flawlessly. Seems like this issue is isolated to Safari.

**Update 2**

I've profiled Safari activity during file uploads. For whatever reason, it sometimes gets into an endless loop of repetitive page rendering.

Comment: This is probably a bug with Safari, and there's not much you can do. You might want to look into the log files of Safari (if available), or see if something is logged to the dev console. Because your code looks good.

Comment: @Info-Screen yes, it looks like a Safari bug. It sometimes gets into a loop trying to render the page instead of finishing the upload. When I manually kill the rendering process the upload continues and terminates fine. Although I don't thinks there is a solution to this problem, I'll leave this question open for others to be aware of the issue.